# How do I turn off Spacemacs’s tildes on empty lines?

Tags: evil, spacemacs, fringe

I just installed [Spacemacs](http://spacemacs.org), mainly for its nifty defaults. One default I'm not so pleased about is that it puts tildes on empty lines in the file.

I've tried putting `(setq vi-tilde-fringe nil)` and `(setq indicate-empty-lines nil)` inside the `dotspacemacs/user-config` function, which seem to have no effect.

How can I get rid of all these messy tildes once and for all?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Toggle

You can toggle it off with `(spacemacs/toggle-vi-tilde-fringe-off)`, you can get the list of all toggles in `helm-spacemacs` accessible via `SPC f e h` or `SPC h SPC` in more recent versions. Every toggle in this list have 3 functions associated to them, if we take `vi-tilde-fringe` then the functions are:

- `spacemacs/toggle-vi-tilde-fringe` (toggle the state on and off)
- `spacemacs/toggle-vi-tilde-fringe-on` (force the toggle state to on)
- `spacemacs/toggle-vi-tilde-fringe-off` (force the toggle state to off)

To get the name of the function associated to a key binding use `SPC h d k` (or `C-h k`) and type the key binding, with the `vi-tilde-fringe` example this is `SPC h d k SPC T ~` (in most recent version) and you should get the function name.

## Excluded packages

Another way to remove the tildes is to exclude the package `vi-tilde-fringe` from your configuration by adding `vi-tilde-fringe` to your dotfile variable `dotspacemacs-excluded-packages`. This will have the effect of completely removing the package and all its associated configuration from your Spacemacs.

Once again to get the package name you can try `helm-spacemacs` and type tilde in the helm buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method that worked great for me:

```
M-x customize-group RET vi-tilde-fringe RET
```

which inserted:

```
 '(global-vi-tilde-fringe-mode nil)
```

in (custom-set-variables) in .spacemacs.